# click on another link first link css remove and ul display

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I click 1st link drop-down slide down and class change of arrow, but when i open 1st link and click on the second link 1st link class not change.
here is my sample code

```js
$(".navclick").click(function(event) { 
 $('.navslidedown ul').each(function(){
 $(this).slideUp();
 
  });
  var $slide = $(this).next('.navslidedown ul');
  if ($slide.is(':visible')) {
      $slide.slideUp();
  }else{
      $slide.slideDown();       
  }
  
 
});

$('.navclick').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('navupclick').sibling().removeClass('navupclick');
});
```

```css
.navslidedown{  float: left;    width: 95%;}
.navslidedown ul{display:none}
.navslidedown li{ display:block; background:#e8ce49;    border-bottom: 1px solid #fbdc3b; margin-bottom:20px}

.navslidedown li a{padding-left:44px}
.navclick{background: url(http://54.85.78.249/design/dna/images/dpdwnarow.png) no-repeat center 0px;         display: block;   margin-bottom:15px; cursor:pointer}

.navupclick{background: url(http://54.85.78.249/design/dna/images/dpuparow.png) no-repeat center 0px;       display: block;   margin-bottom:15px   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navslidedown">
<a  title="India"  class="navclick">India</a>
    
     <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Delhi</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Mumbai</a></li>
     </ul>
     </div>
     
     <div class="navslidedown">
     <a  title="India"  class="navclick">world</a>
    
     <ul>
     <li><a href="#">USA</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Australia</a></li>
     </ul>
     </div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Abzalabbas/3vxxomcn/1/

Comment: Add the relevant code here at SO, if you can create fiddle then sure can create a snippet, click `<>` See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @afzal Check if you are looking for this https://jsfiddle.net/83onh68k/

Comment: Thanx its working :)

Comment: @afzal I have posted it as answer.Please accept if it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code used to toggle the class.Instead of that remove the class `navupclick` form all anchor tag and add the class `navupclick` to the clicked anchor tag

```js
$(".navclick").click(function(event) { 

  $('.navclick').removeClass('navupclick');
  

 $('.navslidedown ul').each(function(){
   $(this).slideUp(); 
  });
  var $slide = $(this).next('.navslidedown ul');
  if ($slide.is(':visible')) {
      $slide.slideUp();
  }else{
      $slide.slideDown();   
     $(this).addClass('navupclick');
  }
  
 
});
```

```css
.navslidedown{  float: left;    width: 95%;}
.navslidedown ul{display:none}
.navslidedown li{ display:block; background:#e8ce49;    border-bottom: 1px solid #fbdc3b; margin-bottom:20px}

.navslidedown li a{padding-left:44px}
.navclick{background: url(http://54.85.78.249/design/dna/images/dpdwnarow.png) no-repeat center 0px;         display: block;   margin-bottom:15px; cursor:pointer}

.navupclick{background: url(http://54.85.78.249/design/dna/images/dpuparow.png) no-repeat center 0px;       display: block;   margin-bottom:15px   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navslidedown">
<a  title="India"  class="navclick">India</a>
    
     <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Delhi</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Mumbai</a></li>
     </ul>
     </div>
     
     <div class="navslidedown">
     <a  title="India"  class="navclick">world</a>
    
     <ul>
     <li><a href="#">USA</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Australia</a></li>
     </ul>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply a change in your jQuery `$('.navclick').click(function() {`

```js
$(".navclick").click(function(event) {
  $('.navslidedown ul').each(function() {
    $(this).slideUp();
  });
  var $slide = $(this).next('.navslidedown ul');
  if ($slide.is(':visible')) {
    $slide.slideUp();
  } else {
    $slide.slideDown();
  }


});

$('.navclick').click(function() {
  $("a.navupclick").not(this).removeClass("navupclick");
  $(this).toggleClass('navupclick');
});
```

```css
.navslidedown {
  float: left;
  width: 95%;
}

.navslidedown ul {
  display: none
}

.navslidedown li {
  display: block;
  background: #e8ce49;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fbdc3b;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

.navslidedown li a {
  padding-left: 44px
}

.navclick {
  background: url(http://54.85.78.249/design/dna/images/dpdwnarow.png) no-repeat center 0px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.navupclick {
  background: url(http://54.85.78.249/design/dna/images/dpuparow.png) no-repeat center 0px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navslidedown">
  <a title="India" class="navclick">India</a>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Delhi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mumbai</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="navslidedown">
  <a title="India" class="navclick">world</a>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">USA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Australia</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```